# How to retrieve NSDate from date time format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I want to check two dates: one is in my plist in the following `NSString` format   `2013-08-03 12:26:33 +0000`

But, I only need  `2013-08-03`, how can I remove rest of the time values? Please help me.

I am checking dates using following code, it's working for me. But I only need to retrieve the date part in  `2013-08-03 12:26:33 +0000`

```
 NSString *start = @"2013-08-03 ";
    NSString *end = @"2013-08-05";

    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
    NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];


    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:endDate
                                                         options:0];

    NSLog(@"%ld", [components day]);
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do just want a string like "2013-08-03" from a given "2013-08-03 12:26:33" date or you want each piece of the date (day, mont and year) separately?

Comment: i want like this "2013-08-03"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if all you want it's just a string with the date part, simply use a dateFormatter, similar what you've done before.

Assuming that you have a reference to some date that you want a string part of it, I encapsulated a method that returns a string with the date part:

```
-(NSString*) stringDatePartOf:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

For example, if you pass a date with the value `2013-08-03 12:26:33 +0000`, this method will return `2013-08-03` , like you wanted.

Comment: oh  great thanks alot...if u dont mind can u answer my this question  please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032249/asynchronous-image-loading-is-not-working